# ERROR [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/build:latest

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, build, dockerfile, devops

When I run this command `docker-compose up -d --build` to build an image, I get this issue:

> pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed (did you mean buid?)

> The build output you provided indicates that the Docker build process encountered an error while trying to load metadata for the image "docker.io/library/build:latest." The error message suggests that there is an issue with pulling the specified image from the container registry.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbNdW.png]

I'm trying to solve the issue so I change this config of docker

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy99s.png]

but it's the same thing.